# Convergence? find $r$ and $p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We let $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)^r}{n^p}$ and for $p=1$, I have to find all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)^r}{n}$ is convergent. I can not find any value for $r$ where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)^r}{n}$ is convergent?

Can it be a cheating question? Or if it is not a cheating question can anybody help me with a hint?

And I have another question: Again for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)^r}{n^p}$ I have to find all values $r,p\in\mathbb R$ where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)^r}{n^p}$ is convergent.

I think that if $r=0$ and $p>1$ then we have convergence by a theorem in my book. But are these the only possible values ​​of $r$ and $p$ where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)^r}{n^p}$ is  convergent?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "cheating question". I think you didn't notice that $r$ could be negative.

Anyway I'll give you a hint that will solve both question:

By the integral test it is enough to find all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ for which

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{\log(x)^r}{x^p} dx$$ converges. Change variables $x\rightarrow e^x$ to get

$$\int_2^\infty e^x \cdot \frac{x^r}{e^{px}}dx = \int_2^\infty \frac{x^r}{e^{(p-1)x}}dx$$

Remember that $r,p$ can be negative. Specifically, consider the cases $p>1,p=1,p<1$ separately.

Comment: Thank you a lot now it make sense. I can use this integral test and your rewrite of the term. If p=1 then back we have $x^r$  which is convergent for <−1  by the theorem in my book (p-Series Convergence). It make sense that the integral is finite if >1 and r$\in$R, but how can I show it? I need help for that

Answer (score 1):

[Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) states that - given a non-increasing sequence $(a_n)$ of non-negative reals,
$$\sum a_n \text{ converges iff } \sum 2^na_{2^n} \text{ converges.}$$

The sequence you've written is certainly non-negative (regardless of $r$ and $p$). If $p = 1$, then the sequence will eventually be non-increasing and hence, we can apply the test. This means that we're looking for the values of $r$ for which
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n\dfrac{(\log(2^n))^r}{2^n} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (n\log2)^r = (\log 2)^r \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^r$$
converges.

Clearly, if $r \ge 0$, then that cannot happen. In fact, you may use the condensation test again to show that the above converges iff $r < -1$.

---

In the case of a general $r$ and $p$, you would certainly need $p > 0$, else the $n^\text{th}$ term of the sequence itself would diverge otherwise. If $p > 0$, then once again, we may use the condensation test to reduce the problem to the convergence of
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^r}{2^{n(p-1)}}.$$
(I have ignored a factor of $(\log 2)^r$ as that doesn't affect anything.)

---

**Case 1.** $p - 1 < 0.$
In this case, we have that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^r}{2^{n(p-1)}} = \infty,$$
regardles of $r$. Thus, the series can definitely not converge.

---

**Case 2.** $p - 1 = 0$. This is case the $p = 1$ which was done earlier.

---

**Case 3.** $p - 1 > 0$. Let $\chi = 2^{p-1}.$ We have that $\chi > 1.$ Let $r \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. (But fixed.)
The summation of earlier now becomes
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^r}{\chi^{n}}.$$

Note that for $n$ sufficiently large, we must have $n^r < \chi^{n/2}$. (This is because $x^r/\chi^{x/2} \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.)

Thus, the series can be bounded by $C/\chi^{n/2}$ for an appropriate constant $C$. Now, note that $\sqrt{\chi} > 1$ and thus, the geometric series
$$C\sum\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\chi}}\right)^n$$
converges.

---

Thus, we conclude with the following:

1. For $p < 1$, the series never converges for any value of $r$.
2. For $p = 1$, the series converges iff $r < -1$.
3. For $p > 1$, the series converges for all values of $r$.

Comment: Thank you. I think i can use your rewrite $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^r}{2^{n(p-1)}}.$$. If p=1 then back we have $^$ which is convergent for <−1 by the theorem in my book (p-Series Convergence). It make sense that it is convergent if >1 and r∈R, but how can I show it? I need help for that

Comment: I'm not sure what you didn't get. I think I have outlined everything in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot now it make sense. I can use this integral test and your rewrite of the term. If p=1 then back we have $x^r$  which is convergent for <−1  by the theorem in my book (p-Series Convergence). It make sense that the integral is finite if >1 and r$\in$R, but how can I show it? I need help for that